# Bash Script to Rename Files Based on Size

Tags: rename

I have a bash script that renames files in a folder according to input from a command prompt:

```
echo "Please rename and press enter" read rename 

if [ -z "$rename" ]; then 
  printf "no caption was selected, aborting!\n"
  exit 1
fi 

printf "rename is $rename\n" count=1

for i in *.jpg; do 
  j=printf "%04d" $count
  j="$rename"$j".jpg"
  count=$((count + 1))
  mv "$i" $j
done  
fi 
shift 
done
```

How can I modify this script so that the files in the folder are renamed according to their size?

If I sort the files according to size, they will look like this in the folder:

```
a009      978kb
a001      567kb
a003      499kb
a008      432kb
```

So I want the resulting files to be renamed:

```
a001      978kb
a002      567kb
a003      499kb
a004      432kb
```

Comment: `j=printf "%04d" $count` would give you an `%04d: no such job` error. You've forgotten `$(...)`.  Also, this line and the next could be written `printf -v j "%s%04d.jpg" "$rename" "$count"` in `bash`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main trick is to replace

```bsh
    for i in *.jpg
```

with

```bsh
    for i in $(ls -S *.jpg)
```

however, as Kusalananda's pointed out, this assumes "educated" file names (no spaces, no control characters), so here is a different approach:

```bsh
count=1
ls -S --escape *.jpg | while read f; do
    n=$(printf "%04d" $count)
    ((count++))
    mv --no-clobber "$f" "$rename$n.jpg"
done
```

`-S` sorts by decreasing file size
`--escape` prevents names with embedded newlines causing damage
`--no-clobber` prevents overwriting destination files in case the script is run twice

P.S.
Ole Tange's answer is a very nice efficient way of doing the same, but you probably won't see the difference unless you routinely rename thousands files.

Comment: Your improved code only renames the biggest file, but doesn't rename the other files.

Comment: Thanks, corrected. Unfortunately I am still presumptuous enough to think that I can write a Bash script without testing it...

Answer (score 5):

Something like this:

```
echo "Please rename and press enter"
read rename 

ls |
  # prepend filename with file size in bytes
  parallel stat -c %s,,sep,,%n --  |
  # sort by number
  sort -n |
  # rename to sequencenumber followed by size in bytes
  parallel -q --colsep ,,sep,, mv {2} "$rename"{#}_{1}
```

Comment: I couldn't try your solution because I can't get GNU Parallel to work with Windows Subsystem for Linux. I use WSL on a Windows 10 machine. I successfully installed GNU Parallel, but for some reason when I try to run your code I get an error saying that Parallel can't be found.

Comment: For some reason GNU Parallel is now working on my machine. I changed `sort -n` to `sort -n -r`. `sort -n` was placing the biggest size files backwards, so that the biggest file was at the bottom of the renaming scheme.

Comment: Since I'm using this in a bash script that renames the files according to my input at a command prompt I would like to remove rename the files with "a". I want the files to be renamed to whatever I type at the command prompt. This is a snippet of the bash script with your code incorporated: `j="$rename"$j".jpg"; ls | parallel stat -c %s,,sep,,%n -- | sort -n -r | parallel --colsep ,,sep,, mv {2} a{#}_$j;` How can I modify this so that placing an "a" in the name is removed?

Comment: This gives me good results: `g=".jpg"; j="$rename"$j".jpg"; ls | parallel stat -c %s,,sep,,%n -- | sort -n -r | parallel --colsep ,,sep,, mv {2} $rename{#}$g; done`

Answer (score 2):

In the `zsh` shell:

```sh
typeset -Z 3 count=0
for name in *.jpg(.DNOL); do
    count=$(( count + 1 ))
    mv -i -- "$name" "a$count.jpg"
done
```

This would iterate over all regular files with an `.jpg` filename suffix in the current directory, in the order of largest to smallest.  For each file, it would rename it to `aNNN.jpg` where `NNN` is the zero-filled integer count of files processed so far.

The `(.DNOL)` glob qualifier orders the matching filenames in the correct order using `OL` ("revers order by length"), and selects only regular files (including hidden names) using `.D` ("regular files, and dot-files").  The `N` makes the pattern expand to nothing if there is no matching name ("null glob").

This would work on all valid filenames on any Unix system with `zsh` installed.

To use this from `bash`:

```
zsh -c 'typeset -Z 3 count=0
for name in *.jpg(.DNOL); do
    count=$(( count + 1 ))
    mv -i -- "$name" "a$count.jpg"
done'
```

If you have a variable `$rename` that you want to pass in as a filename prefix instead of using `a`:

```
zsh -c 'typeset -Z 3 count=0
for name in *.jpg(.DNOL); do
    count=$(( count + 1 ))
    mv -i -- "$name" "$1$count.jpg"
done' zsh "$rename"
```

Note that the `zsh` on the last line is not a typo and that the value of `$rename` is used as `$1` inside the `zsh -c` script.

Comment: It is possible for more than one file to be the same size.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey It sure is, and in that case, the files that have the same size will sort according to their original names.